# [Partition Benifit on Indexed Column]

Tags: mysql, partitioning

```
 CREATE TABLE ofRoster (
  `rosterID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `jid` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `sub` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `ask` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `recv` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rosterID`),
  KEY `ofRoster_unameid_idx` (`username`),
  KEY `ofRoster_jid_idx` (`jid`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


 CREATE TABLE `ofRoster_par` (
  `rosterID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` int(64) NOT NULL,
  `jid` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `sub` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `ask` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `recv` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `rosterID` (`rosterID`,`username`),
  KEY `ofRoster_unameid_idx` (`username`),
  KEY `ofRoster_jid_idx` (`jid`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=412595 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (username)
PARTITIONS 10 */ ;
```

I created partition on username so that when i use select command it need to search on one partition only.
But i am not sure if this will be benifitial as there is already a index on username.

```
explain SELECT count(*) FROM ofRoster_par WHERE username='1';
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ofRoster_par | ref  | ofRoster_unameid_idx | ofRoster_unameid_idx | 4       | const |  120 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+


explain SELECT count(*) FROM ofRoster WHERE username='1';
+----+-------------+----------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ofRoster | ref  | ofRoster_unameid_idx | ofRoster_unameid_idx | 66      | const |  120 | Using where; Using index |
```

Right now there are just 400 000 records on the table but on the production records will be around 80 million.

Time taken by both query is also the same :-(

Comment: I would recommend reading [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-does-table-partitioning-help) post

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY HASH` is, in my opinion, *useless*.

In your example, `INDEX(username)` on a non-partitioned table would probably be faster than using `PARTITION BY HASH(username)`.

You already have such an index.  How fast was it?

Here's what is happening:

With partitioning:

1. pick partition
2. use `KEY(username)` (and not the data) to do the `COUNT(*)` inside the index (note "Using index")

Without partitioning:

1. use `KEY(username)` (and not the data) to do the `COUNT(*)` inside the index (note "Using index")

Other comments:

- If `username` is unique, consider making it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `rosterID`.  (You may want to keep `rosterID` because it is smaller and used for `JOINing` to several other tables.)
- Bug:  You say `INT(64)` where you meant `VARCHAR(64)`.  This may have impacted your timing test.
- "Prefix indexes" `(jid(255))` are rarely useful.  Let's see how you are using it.
- 80M rows does not warrant `BIGINT` (8 bytes); `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes) can handle 400 crore.
- You understand that `latin1` limits you to western European languages?
- When using `EXPLAIN` with partitioned tables, use `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...`.  You may get some surprises.